# Using .map() on object to get value from different parent keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using nodeJS and have the following object called `object` containing the following:

```
{ first:
    { bool: false,
      date: '2018-07-15' },
  second:
    { bool: false,
      date: '2019-08-05' },
  third:
    { bool: false,
      date: '2019-09-02' } 
}
```

I want to get the `bool` value from `first`,`second` and `third`. Is there a way to do this using `.map()`?

Extracting the keys `first`,`second` and `third` from `object` I understand using `Object.keys(object)`, but how do I continue with `.map()` to dig to get the value of all three `bool`?

Comment: IMO structure your data like `[{code: "first", bool: false}, {code: "second", ...}]` and then use the appropriate array function (like map).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `map` `Object.values` of `object` to their `bool` property:

```js
var object = {
  first: {
    bool: false,
    date: '2018-07-15'
  },
  second: {
    bool: false,
    date: '2019-08-05'
  },
  third: {
    bool: false,
    date: '2019-09-02'
  }
}

var bools = Object.values(object).map(o => o.bool);

console.log(bools);
```